# Stack of stacks possible?

Tags: stack

A doubt crossed my mind while studying stack, can we have a stack of many stacks, just like array matrices are array of many arrays? If yes, how can I possibly implement it?

Comment: Yes, you can have a stack of stacks. What language do you want to implement it in? Have you given any thought as to how you would implement such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can totally have stacks of stacks. [In Python for example, `list` can be used as a stack.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks) So a list of list is essentially stack of stacks.
In C++, you can also declare a `std::stack<std::stack<int> >` to be a stack of int stacks.